# Access TextBox from Static method in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, static

I have 2 classes: MyForm and Database

In MyForm I have a method to change a label text to show error:

```
public void printError(string text){
    label1.Text = text;
}
```

My Database class needs to access that method too, so I make it static:

```
public static void printError(MyForm form, string text){
    form.label1.Text = text;
}
```

Now the problem is, **how do I call that method from Database class**?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952023/in-c-sharp-net-how-does-one-access-a-control-from-a-static-method) I found said that I need to pass MyForm into Database's contructor like this:

```
class MyForm : Form{
    Database db;
    public Form(){
        db = new Database(this);
    }
}

class Database{
    MyForm form;
    public Database(MyForm f){
        form = f;
    }
    ...
    //then I can access the printError like this
    MyForm.printError(form, "You got error");
}
```

I tried that and it **freezes the form**. Any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: You seriously need to rethink your design. For what possible reason does your database need access to your UI? There are many ways for reporting errors that do not involve a poor design. Consider throwing exceptions instead.

Comment: This is pretty terrible from a design perspective. The `Database` class should have no knowledge of your UI. Instead the methods of `Database` should return any errors to the caller, then the caller can handle how to display them.

Comment: I need to access the UI Label to print the error like "Wrong username" or something. Currently I use MessageBox which is quite intrusive.

EDIT:
So should I put the error message as `return` and handle it in MyForm?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with displaying the error in a label, we are just saying that the `Database` class is not the correct place to put the display code.

Comment: @DarcCode: when the UI code calls the database code, the database code needs a way to pass errors back, usually via some sort of object, or maybe an exception. The UI then uses the information in the object/exception to display an appropriate message.

Comment: We need more information. What is the `Database` class doing around the `printError` call? Is it making that call repeatedly in rapid succession, or from another thread, say, in a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: I don't see why this question is getting downvoted. Yes, it's horrid design, but this is where we help people make better design decisions and figure out what they are really asking for.

Comment: The `Database` need to print the error like "Wrong password" to the Label in `MyForm`. It is not rapid call, just when the user do something wrong. 

I don't use `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: @DarcCode: the Database does NOT need to print anything. Please read up on separation of concerns. The UI will print things. The Database layer will notify the UI that something went wrong. Or rather, it will notify anyone who wants to know how database operations went.

Comment: Why do you need your database to do the error printing? If at all the password entered is wrong, you have several other ways to notify that the login credentials are wrong. You better rethink your approach

Comment: If you want an approach that I follow for this, i can give you an example.. Or if you insist on following the same approach, its upto you

Comment: @Cdeez can you give an example for better approach?

Comment: @DarcCode : you only want to show an error message in a label when the login credentials are wrong. Is that the only thing?

Comment: I also need the error message for wrong data type (the user input string but the database column is Integer). **EDIT**: The answer from @veredesmarald already solved my problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of how you can achieve this without your data layer knowing about your UI:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    Database db;

    public Form()
    {
        db = new Database(this);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var errors = db.Login("", "");
        if (errors.Any())
            label1.Text = errors.First(); // Or you can display all all of them
    }
}

class Database
{    
    public List<string> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            errors.Add("Username is required");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            errors.Add("Password is required");

        [...]

        return errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is really a simple one.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Matthew Ferreira and others have stated the design is not idea, but here's something to get you started.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var dataAccess = new Repository();

        dataAccess.ExecuteQuery();

        if (dataAccess.Exceptions.Any())
        {
            // display your error messages
            form.label1.Text = dataAccess.Exceptions.Select(x => x.ToString());
        }
    }
}

class Repository
{
    private readonly HashSet<Exception> _exceptions = new HashSet<Exception>();

    public IEnumerable<Exception> Exceptions
    {
        get { return _exceptions; }
    }

    public int ExecuteQuery()
    {
        var numberOfRecordsAffected = 0;

        try
        {
            // do something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // normall catching exceptions is a bad idea
            // and you should really catch the exception at the 
            // layer best equiped to deal with it
            _exceptions.Add(ex);
        }

        // but, for the purpose of this example we might want to add some logic to try the query on another database ????
        try
        {
            // do something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _exceptions.Add(ex);
        }

        return numberOfRecordsAffected;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that this is a good practices. I will take note of this for my future coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up "seperation of concerns". Its really bad to mix your UI code with you Database Access Layer (DAL). Better to bind the UI to business objects that are populated via a DAL.

To let the UI know about an error you could simply use a delegate.

```
namespace OperationErrorDelegate
{
    public delegate void OperationErrorHandler(Exception ex);

    public class DAL
    {
        public event OperationErrorHandler ReportError;

        public void DoDALOperationThatCausesError()
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 1;
                int j = 0;
                int k = i/j;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ReportError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add this code to the form:

```
using System ;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OperationErrorDelegate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DAL DAL = new DAL();
            DAL.ReportError += new OperationErrorHandler(DAL_OperationErrorProgress);
            DAL.DoDALOperationThatCausesError();
        }

    private void DAL_OperationErrorProgress(Exception ex)
    {
        label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It is quite too complicated for a newb.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the OP's requirement is to display an error message in a label, when the credentials are wrong:

```
   private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;password=abc;database=mydb");
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from emp where name='" + textBox1.Text + "'and pwd='" + textBox2.Text + "'",con);
         con.Open();
         MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read()) 
        {    //successful
            //navigate to next page or whatever you want
        }
        else
            Label1.Text("Invalid userid or password");
        con.Close();
    }
```

And if you need `error message for wrong data type (the user input string but the database column is Integer)`, then use validations at client side. You dont need to do it at backend, since that will be a burden. 
You can use regular expressions for that in the `button_click` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will put the validation in client side.

Comment: Fails to consider separation of concerns.