# FileSystemWatcher and toolStripStatusLabel

Tags: c#

I am trying to update the toolStripStatusLabel text from FileSystemWatcher object OnChanged event but i am not able to getting it done.

Tried this code,but what would be the best way to do it ?
I am having problem at the line not displaying the text. ( no errors just no txt)

```
toolStripStatusLabel.Text = txt + " " + newfile;
```

Source Code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

 namespace Packet
{
public partial class Main
{ 
    [DllImport("7plus.dll")]
    public static extern int Do_7plus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string args);

    #region CreateFile Watch
    public void CreateFileWatcher(string path)
    {
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = path,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
            Filter = "*.*"
        };
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region OnChange
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        string newfile;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
        string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        if (ext == ".7pl")
        {
            newfile = path + file + ".7pl";
            string lockfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Lock\\"  + file + ".lock";
            string logfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Log\\" + file + ".LOG";
            string outpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Out\\" ; 
            if (!File.Exists(lockfile))
            {
                using (File.Create(lockfile))
                {
                    var args = newfile + " -SAVE " + outpath + " -LOG " + logfile;
                    Run7Plus(args);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(lockfile);
            }
        }
        else  if (ext == ".lock" || ext == ".LOG")
        { }
        else
            {
            newfile = path + file + ".P01";
            string lockfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Lock\\" + file + ".lock";
            string logfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Log\\" + file + ".LOG";
            string outpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Out\\";
            if (!File.Exists(lockfile))
            {
                using (File.Create(lockfile))
                {
                    var args = newfile + " -SAVE " + outpath + " -LOG " + logfile;
                    Run7Plus(args); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(lockfile);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion OnChange 

    #region  Run 7plus
    public static void Run7Plus(string newfile)
    {
        var args = newfile ;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        int rn = Do_7plus(args);

        using (Main main = new Main())
        {
            main.Msg(newfile, rn);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region   is File locked
    protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }
        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }
    #endregion

    #region    msg
    public void Msg(string newfile, int rn) 
    {
        string txt;
        switch (rn)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    txt = "No errors detected.";
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    txt = "Write error.";
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    txt = "File not found.";
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    txt = "7PLUS header not found.";
                    break;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    txt = "File does not contain expected part.";
                    break;
                }
            case 5:
                {
                    txt = "7PLUS header corrupted.";
                    break;
                }
            case 6:
                {
                    txt = "No filename for extracting defined.";
                    break;
                }
            case 7:
                {
                    txt = "invalid error report / correction / index file.";
                    break;
                }
            case 8:
                {
                    txt = "Max number of parts exceeded.";
                    break;
                }
            case 9:
                {
                    txt = "Bit 8 stripped.";
                    break;
                }
            case 10:
                {
                    txt = "User break in test_file();";
                    break;
                }
            case 11:
                {
                    txt = "Error report generated.";
                    break;
                }
            case 12:
                {
                    txt = "Only one or no error report to join.";
                    break;
                }
            case 13:
                {
                    txt = "Error report/cor-file does not refer to the same original file.";
                    break;
                }
            case 14:
                {
                    txt = "Couldn't write 7plus.fls.";
                    break;
                }
            case 15:
                {
                    txt = "File size of original file and the size reported in err/cor-file not equal.";
                    break;
                }
            case 16:
                {
                    txt = "Correction not successful.";
                    break;
                }
            case 17:
                {
                    txt = "No CRC found in err/cor-file.";
                    break;
                }
            case 18:
                {
                    txt = "Time stamp in meta file differs from that in the correction file.";
                    break;
                }

            case 19:
                {
                    txt = "Meta file already exists.";
                    break;
                }
            case 20:
                {
                    txt = "Can't encode files with 0 file length.";
                    break;
                }
            case 21:
                {
                    txt = " Not enough memory available.";
                    break;
                }


            default:
                {
                    txt = "?";
                    break;
                }
        }
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = txt + " " + newfile;
    }
    #endregion

}
}
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question earlier today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952023/in-c-sharp-net-how-does-one-access-a-control-from-a-static-method)

A static method doesn't have access to members like toolStripStatusLabel because it is not a part of that instance.

To continue the way you've been doing it, your "TheIncomingDataClass" should have a reference to the MainForm object with which it should interface. When you create an instance of this class (presumably from an instance method of MainForm), you will need to pass in a reference to this MainForm object.

```
class TheIncomingDataClass{
    MainForm form;

    public TheIncomingDataClass(MainForm form){
        this.form = form;
    }
}

class MainForm : Form{
    MainForm(){
        new TheIncomingDataClass(this);
    }
}
```

However, as suggested by Bugs, you probably would be better off making this an event on TheIncomingDataClass and subscribing to it from MainForm.

```
class IncomingMessageEventArgs : EventArgs{
    IncomingMessageType message;

    public IncomingMessageType Message{get{return message;}}

    public IncomingMessageEventArgs(IncomingMessageType message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class TheIncomingDataClass{
    public event EventHandler<IncomingMessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(IncomingMessageEventArgs e){
        if(MessageReceived != null)
            MessageReceived(this, e);
    }

    public void IncomingMessage(IncomingMessageType message){
        OnMessageReceived(new IncomingMessageEventArgs(message));
    }
}

class MainForm : Form{
    MainForm(){
        new TheIncomingDataClass().MessageReceived +=
            (s, e)=>txtDisplayMessages.AppendText(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```