# c# Update WinForm GUI textBox from another class/event

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am learning to use API of PtGrey camera.

And I have the following class example provided by the company for device arrival and removal.

```
    Class SystemEventListener: ManagedInterfaceEvent
    {
        private IManagedSystem system;

        public SystemEventListener(IManagedSystem sys) { system = sys; }


        protected override void OnDeviceArrival(UInt64 serialNumber)
        {
            int count = system.GetCameras().Count;

            Console.WriteLine("System event listener:");
            Console.WriteLine("\tThere {0} {1} {2} on the system.", (count == 1 ? "is" : "are"), count, (count == 1 ? "device" : "devices"));
        }

        protected override void OnDeviceRemoval(UInt64 serialNumber)
        {
            int count = system.GetCameras().Count;

            Console.WriteLine("System event listener:");
            Console.WriteLine("\tThere {0} {1} {2} on the system.", (count == 1 ? "is" : "are"), count, (count == 1 ? "device" : "devices"));
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to adapt this to my win form environment. After struggling to update the GUI from this class, I managed to follow the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952188) for updating the text box. However, it involves modifying the program.cs file.

My question is how to update the textbox from these events in another class, preferably without touching Program.cs.

I did try using delegate/event, etc. but every time, I encountered Null Reference Exception on my main form (Form1) instance. I must have done something wrong obviously.

Below is my current implementation which works but I am hoping for another way wihtout modifying the program.cs.

Program.cs

```
    public static Form1 MainForm;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
```

Form1.cs

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SystemEventListener systemEventListener = new SystemEventListener(system);
        system.RegisterInterfaceEvent(systemEventListener);
    }

    private void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        textBoxCamProperties.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + "-" + value + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public class SystemEventListener : ManagedInterfaceEvent
    {
        private IManagedSystem system;

        public SystemEventListener(IManagedSystem sys) { system = sys; }

        protected override void OnDeviceArrival(UInt64 serialNumber)
        {
            //int count = system.GetCameras().Count;

            Program.MainForm.AppendTextBox("Device attached\r\n");


        }

       protected override void OnDeviceRemoval(UInt64 serialNumber)
        {
            //int count = system.GetCameras().Count;

            Program.MainForm.AppendTextBox("Device removed\r\n");

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: Kudos to #Handbag Crab! I can use his method without touching Program.cs. :-)

And could someone also show me how to use event/delegate properly in this particular case as well?

Cheers and Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Since you use (register the interface) already in constructor, it is possible, that the first event is fired even before the constructor ends and the value in `Program.MainForm` is still `null`. Try to register events only in `OnLoad` function of the form.

Comment: Hi, #Julo Thanks for the help. I did try on Form1_Load event but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Program.MainForm.AppendTextBox("Device removed\r\n");
```

Use:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>().FirstOrDefault()?.AppendTextBox("Device removed\r\n");
```

Application.OpenForms is a static property giving you access to all the forms that are open within the application.

The above linq line checks the OpenForms list for any of the type MainForm then pulls the first one, if it exists, and calls AppendTextBox on it.

The `?.` operator does the null check for you. It's equivalent of this code:

```
MainForm form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>().FirstOrDefault();
if (form != null)
    form.AppendTextBox("Device removed\r\n");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, #Handbag Crab. I learned something new today. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the ref word: read this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

So, in the constructor of Form1 you can refered to program like this:

```
public Form1(ref Program myProgram){
    myProgram.MainForm.AppendTextBox("Device removed \r\n");
}
```

And in Program.CS you can add this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Program myProgram = this;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MainForm = new Form1(ref myProgram);

    Application.Run(MainForm);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I downvoted your answer because it adds confusion. You are talking about passing a static class as a reference, this is not possible and will raise a compile-time error. I also suspect that you misunderstood the problem.

Comment: #A.Gerber, Thanks for your help. I tried and as mentioned by #Fixation, I encountered an error.

Comment: Ok, sorry so. Good luck with that :)